# Does the Masuda Method work with a Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Say I'm using a Japanese Ditto or Japanese whatever I want a shiny of paired with a Ditto. Do I still get the increased chance of of shiny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Masuda Method still works in this generation and with Ditto(s/es). In fact, you don't even have to use a Japanese Ditto. So long as one of the Pokemon is from a different region than the other, then they have an increased chance of breeding a shiny Pokemon.